# Enumerate relative paths to files in a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to generate a file containing the relative paths to all the files in a directory. So far I have this batch file:

```
@echo off
for /R  "C:\TEST" %%f in (*) do echo %%f
```

Its output is:

```
C:\TEST\linux.txt
C:\TEST\riddles.txt
C:\TEST\one\limerick.txt
C:\TEST\two\art.txt
C:\TEST\two\computers.txt
```

I want the output to be:

```
linux.txt
riddles.txt
one\limerick.txt
two\art.txt
two\computers.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    pushd "c:\test"
    for /f "tokens=* delims=\." %%a in ('
        xcopy /l /s ".\*" "%temp%" ^| find "."
    ') do echo %%a
    popd
```

This uses an `xcopy` to get the list of files with relative paths. The `delims` and `tokens` clauses will remove the initial `.\` from the start of each line, and the `find` command will discard the final line in the `xcopy` output that shows the number of files.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "pd=C:\TEST"
pushd "%pd%"
call :strlen __cd__ clen
rem echo %clen%
for /R  "%pd%" %%f in (*) do (
 set "dirp=%%~ff"
 echo !dirp:~%clen%!
)



exit /b 0


:strlen  StrVar  [RtnVar]
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "s=#!%~1!"
  set "len=0"
  for %%N in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%N,1!" neq "" (
      set /a "len+=%%N"
      set "s=!s:~%%N!"
    )
  )
  endlocal&if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%len%) else echo %len%
exit /b
```

you need the length of the current directory to perform substring operation.