# Display directory structure using relative paths

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to generate a file that contains the directory structure of a given directory, as relative paths. Currently I have the following batch file:

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\TEST"
dir /AD /B /ON /S
popd
```

Its current output is this:

```
C:\TEST\one
C:\TEST\three
C:\TEST\two
C:\TEST\one\a
C:\TEST\three\d
C:\TEST\three\e
C:\TEST\three\f
C:\TEST\two\b
C:\TEST\two\c
```

I want the output to be:

```
one
three
two
one\a
three\d
three\e
three\f
two\b
two\c
```

EDIT: this question is not a duplicate. The other question shows files exclusively, now I need to get directories exclusively (not mixed with files).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enumerate relative paths to files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150896/enumerate-relative-paths-to-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: Same question from the same user.

Comment: Not a duplicate because this time I need directory structure, not showing files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "targetdir=c:\106x"
pushd "%targetdir%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /AD /B /ON /S') DO (SET "dirname=%%a"&ECHO(!dirname:%targetdir%\=!)
popd
GOTO :EOF
```

This should work for you provided the directoryname does not contain `!`

The directorynames are applied to `%%a` and transferred to `dirname` for manipulation. The target directoryname + a closing `\` are then replaced by *nothing* for display.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still have problems. For my purposes I need to add text around the generated relative paths. I have tried modifying the DO section thus: `DO (SET "dirname=%%a"&ECHO rmdir "!dirname:%targetdir%\=!")` but a space is added before the closing quotes.

Comment: Works perfectly happily for me.using your `do` as posted in your comment. If all you're doing is a `rmdir`, why not use the complete directoryname in `%%a`?

Comment: Thanks! My mistake: in my real script I "beautified" the code by adding extra spaces around the `&` character. As for your question, I'm not really using `rmdir` from the _Command Prompt_ but a different kind of `RMDir` from within a special script.